# Split column into rows for every 6 chars in BigQuery

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata

I need to migrate simple spark statement into Bigquery as part of GCP migration.
A table contains 2 columns which need to be split according to spark statements into BigQuery.

in Spark:

`t1 = spark.sql("select col1,col2 from db.table")`

`df1 = t1.withColumn("col2",explode(split(col("col2"), "(?<=\\G......)"))).withColumn("col2",trim(col("col2")))`

Input Table:

```
+----+----------------------+
|col1|                  col2|
+----+----------------------+
|d1|X11   F11   1000KG123456|
|d2|X22   F22   3500Kabcdefgh|
```

Expected output:

```
+------------+
|col1|col2|
+------------+
|d1|     X11|
|d1|     F11|
|d1|  1000KG|
|d1|  123456|
|d2|     X22|
|d2|     F22|
|d2|  3500Ka|
|d2|  bcdefg|
|d2|       h|
```

actually col2 has big value "X11   F11   1000KG123456.........".
In col2 - we need to consider the data each 6 chars.
I tried with few of queries but it did not worked out.
can anyone suggest the relevant bigQuery to convert that spark statement ?
Request to suggest generic query because I have lot of records in it.

Comment: HI, Anyone please suggest a solution. I am blocked. Thank you.

Comment: resolution is here:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66684778/how-to-split-column-data-for-each-6-chars-and-to-form-a-rows-in-bigquery/66689070#66689070)

Answer (score 0):

Use [unnest](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays) and [split](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split):

```
with mytable as (
  select 'd1' as col1, 'X11   F11   1000KG...' as col2 union all
  select 'd2', 'X22   F22   3500K...'
)
select col1, rtrim(rtrim(c2, 'G...'), '...')
from mytable, unnest(split(col2, '   ')) as c2
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for prompt reply. I have given the example data in real table there lot of records in the table. Is it possible to give the generic query instead of hard coded values in it? The split can be based on (?<=\\G......)") also as per the spark statement.

Comment: Yep, any string can be used as a splitter. You can also try `REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL` to split based on regexp expression.

Comment: with mytable as (select col1, col2 from `table`)
select col1 c2
from mytable, unnest(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(col2, '(?<=\\G......) ')) as c2. This is giving me "Cannot parse regular expression: invalid perl operator: (?<" error.

Comment: Ahh, you can use rtrim. Updated the answer.

Comment: I will try this. I have updated the question with little more clear. Can you please revisit.

Comment: Could add more examples of Input and desired Output?

Comment: Sorry, it did not worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230010/discussion-between-rajasekhar-888-and-sergey-geron).