# how to split column data for each 6 chars and to form a rows in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a requirement to split the column data for each 6 characters.

```
Input:
+----+----------------------+
|col1|                  col2|
+----+----------------------+
|d1|X11   F11   1000KG123456|
|d2|X22   F22   3500Kabcdefgh|

Expecting:
+------------+
|col1|col2|
+------------+
|d1|     X11|
|d1|     F11|
|d1|  1000KG|
|d1|  123456|
|d2|     X22|
|d2|     F22|
|d2|  3500Ka|
|d2|  bcdefg|
|d2|       h|
```

I require a generic query not a hard coded ones please. I have huge data in my table.
I have tried with below query it did not worked.

```
with mytable as 
(select col1,col2 from `table_name`)
select col1, c2
from mytable, unnest(SPLIT(col2, '(?<=\\G......)')) as c2
```

where '(?<=\G......)' is the regex used in spark, the same regex is not working in bigquery.
Please help I need to implement this in bigquery in production soon.

Comment: Do you know what the maximum number of characters which would be present in `col2` ?

Comment: as of now 1146, it may differ too.

Comment: Do you have to do this cleanup inside a database, or could you do it somewhere else?

Comment: This is not for any cleanup. after splitting this table I need to join with another table as it contains 6 chars as key. This is for further functional validations.

Comment: Yes, it is a cleanup, as to get to the normalized table you want, you need to do some scrubbing.  Hence, my question above, which you did not answer.

Comment: Ok, is there a solution ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230060/discussion-between-rajasekhar-888-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: No chat...I was merely suggesting that maybe you export your table to something like Notepad++, manipulate the text there, and then reimport into BigQuery.

Comment: Is it not possible to do it in BigQuery without reimporting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query, it will work as expected

```
with mytable as 
(select col1,col2 from `table_name`)
select col1, c2
from mytable, unnest(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(string_field_1, '.{6}')) as c2
```

For more details refer

https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract_all

Comment: Hi SANN3, Thanks a lot for your help and your query is absolutely suitable for my requirement.

Comment: @Rajasekhar888 - not sure what you mean by "suitable" but it definitely does not return expected result - row `|d2|       h|` is missing. see my answer for correct query

Comment: Actually my data correctly splitted to accommodate 6 chars. So did not find the difference. Thanks for the response again.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below

```
select col1, col2
from `project.dataset.table`,
unnest(regexp_extract_all(col2, r'.{1,6}')) col2
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: did you have chance to try and see the difference?